# react-router default page does not work

Tags: apache, reactjs, routes, react-router

When a user clicks refresh on the server, or tries to enter a url path in the application that does not exist, I want them to be directed to the login page.  I thought adding this default route would fix it:

```
<Route path='*' component={LoginPage}/>
```

While it works on the dev server, it does not work in production with Apache.  What am I dong wrong?

Here is my entire routes page:

```
export default (
    <Route path={VC.BASEPATH}>
        <IndexRoute component={LoginPage}/>
        <Route path={VC.BASEPATH} component={App}>
            <Route path={VC.BASEPATH + "home"} component={HomePage}/>
            <Route component={Builder}>
                <Route path={VC.BASEPATH + "builder/admin"} component={AdminPage}/>
                <Route path={VC.BASEPATH + "builder/survey_builder"} component={SurveyBuilderPage}/>
                <Route path={VC.BASEPATH + "builder/survey_details"} component={SurveyDetailsPage}/>
            </Route>
            <Route component={Search}>
                <Route path={VC.BASEPATH + "search/draft"} component={SurveyQueryContainerPage}/>
                <Route path={VC.BASEPATH + "search/prod"} component={ProdSurveyPage}/>
            </Route>
        </Route>
        <Route path={VC.BASEPATH + "preview"} component={PreviewPage}/>
        <Route path='*' component={LoginPage}/>
    </Route>
);
```

Comment: what is the value of VC.BASEPATH ?

Comment: What do you get instead? 404?

Comment: BASEPATH = '/basepath/';

Comment: I get a 404 error whenever I refresh the page or enter a url path that does not match a page.

Comment: how's your backend code? Do you have a catch all route that sends the request back to your index? You need that if you want react-router to handle all requests.

Comment: We have all client side rendering.  There is no server side 'client' code.

Comment: Well, there's at least one server side component in there. What is apache actually doing? Is it just a html file you use? How is this setup?